# Paginação Spring MVC + Spring Data

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data

Bom dia pessoal tudo ? Não estou com um problema em si, apenas algo que quero otimizar. Estou utilizando Spring MVC com Spring Data, para realizar a paginação de resultados, estou fazendo utilizando Pageable dentro do meu repositório. O meu problema é no front-end, digamos que eu tenha 100 páginas, a paginação quebra, ou seja, ele não segue na mesma linha. Queria algo assim, usando a paginação do spring mvc.

[image]

Conforme eu vou clicando nos botões eles são renderizados.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando você utiliza Pageable no Spring Data, você passa a quantidade de resultados que quer que retorne por página, acredito que seu problema de frontend se resolva com sua paginação retornando mesmo numero de registros por página...

Answer (score 1):

Boa tarde!

Em um dos meus projetos utilizei esta solução, toda a sua documentação está no github: https://github.com/jpenren/thymeleaf-spring-data-dialect

Veja se pode lhe ajudar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]